# calculate customer who upgrade their product (MRR Expansion) in mysql or google sheet

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the difference revenue when customer upgrade their product, its called **MRR Expansion**.

How to calculate:
(revenue from customer A which upgrade product to premium this month) - (revenue customer A using basic product in previous month)

in mysql or even in google sheet

my table

| Order month | Customer | Product | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | A | Basic | 100.000 |
| January | B | Basic | 100.000 |
| February | A | Premium A | 200.000 |
| February | B | Premium B | 300.000 |
| March | A | Premium A | 200.000 |
| March | B | Premium B | 300.000 |
| April | A | Premium B | 300.000 |
| April | B | Premium B | 300.000 |

my expectation

| Order month | Customer | Product | Revenue | MRR Expansion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | A | Basic | 100.000 |  |
| January | B | Basic | 100.000 |  |
| February | A | Premium A | 200.000 | 100.000 |
| February | B | Premium B | 300.000 | 200.000 |
| March | A | Premium A | 200.000 |  |
| March | B | Premium B | 300.000 |  |
| April | A | Premium B | 300.000 | 100.000 |
| April | B | Premium B | 300.000 |  |

thank you so much

Comment: which version of mysql are you using ? also, let me know if there will be only 2 rows per customer, basic and premium

Comment: sorry I don't know which version, I suppose the latest. actually there are many rows per customer. we have hundreds customer and I will calculate the MRR for 3 years

Comment: Please update above sample data with customers having 3-4 rows and expected result.

Comment: @AmitVerma just updated my table

Comment: is there any primary key on this table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this but this will not work on previous versions of MySQL :

```
create table orders (Month varchar(20), Customer varchar(20), Product varchar(20), Revenue INT(20));

INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('January', 'A', 'Basic',     100.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('January', 'B', 'Basic',     100.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('February', 'A', 'Premium A',    200.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('February', 'B', 'Premium B',    300.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('March', 'A', 'Premium A',   200.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('March', 'B', 'Premium B',   300.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('April', 'A', 'Premium B',   300.000);
INSERT INTO orders (Month, Customer, Product, Revenue) values ('April', 'B', 'Premium B',   300.000);


SELECT  O.Month, O.Customer, O.Product, O.Revenue, O1.MRR_Expansion 
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT Month, Customer, Product, Revenue, (Revenue - Prev_Revenue)AS MRR_Expansion
    FROM(
        SELECT Month, Customer, Product, Revenue, LAG(Revenue, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY  Customer) Prev_Revenue
        FROM ORDERS
    )t
)O1 ON O.Month = O1.Month AND O.Customer = O1.Customer AND O.Product = O1.Product AND O.Revenue = O1.Revenue
```